# How to display proper error message on browser in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display proper error messages on browser so that i can do analysis on error.
Please provide me name of any gems or plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel?view=asciicast

```
group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
end
```